# listview using AsyncHttpClient

Tags: android, json, listview

I am trying to populate a `ListView` with some values using `ListView AsyncHttpClient`.

I have no idea how to do it with `AsyncHttpClient`

```
public void getFavouriteWS(RequestParams params){
    // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://www.example.com/getfavouriteonline",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        // When the response returned by REST has Http response code '200'
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try {
                // JSON Object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                String favourite_id = obj.getString("favourite_online_id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // When the response returned by REST has Http response code other than '200'
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {
            // When Http response code is '404'
            if(statusCode == 404){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code is '500'
            else if(statusCode == 500){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code other than 404, 500
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My JSON response is,

```
{"favourite_online_id":"3","favourite_online_url":"ddd","favourite_online_status":"0"}{"favourite_online_id":"2","favourite_online_url":"http:\/\/www.google.com","favourite_online_status":"0"}
```

How to populate the above `JSON` response in a `ListView`.

Comment: you json is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple steps to getting this to work. First things first, we need valid JSON coming from your API. I put up a temp endpoint through myJSON you can use for testing `https://api.myjson.com/bins/ssc03`. Follow this format:

```
[
  {
    "favourite_online_id": "3",
    "favourite_online_url": "ddd",
    "favourite_online_status": "0"
  },
  {
    "favourite_online_id": "2",
    "favourite_online_url": "http://www.google.com",
    "favourite_online_status": "0"
  }
]
```

Now that the JSON is valid we can parse it. The version of ASyncHttpClient I used takes different parameters so just focus on the logic inside.

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

public void getFavouriteWS(RequestParams params){
    // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/ssc03",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                // JSON Array from byte[]
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));
                //loop each object in the array 
                for(int i = 0; i< arr.length(); i++) {
                    // get value needed
                    String favourite_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("favourite_online_id");
                    // add value to arrayList
                    values.add(favourite_id);
                }
                // call method to show results
                populateList();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            // When Http response code is '404'
            if(statusCode == 404){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code is '500'
            else if(statusCode == 500){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code other than 404, 500
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I did all of this inside the same file for testing purposes. If you want to encapsulate your API calls into a separate file you will need to create a callback from the API call to your activity or fragment. Inside the file with your listview reference do something like this:

```
public void populateList(){
    //create simple adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    //assign adapter to listview
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```